# Запуск iTunes на Ubuntu 18.04.02

Tags: ubuntu, установка, wine

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно установить iTunes на Ubuntu для редактирования библиотеки Apple Music. При установке напрямую с помощью Wine в конечном счете выдает ошибку. Изначально всплывает окно о невозможности установки программного обеспечения, связанного с iPod'ами, затем окно iTunes с предупреждением о невозможности дальнейшего использования программы и советом о переустановке. С Playonlinux ситуация тоже не очень хорошая: все делаю по инструкции, вот только вместо окна установки iTunes всплывает окно без интерфейса (см. вложения), а далее процесс просто виснет. Есть ли какие-либо решения данной проблемы или альтернативные способы установки? 
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик.

Comment: @Suvitruf, это не системное администрирование?

Comment: @PavelGridin оооочень с натяжкой только если. Лучше уж тут спросить https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ну там по аглицки надо знать